# Warning regarding NA values while converting time

Tags: r, functional-programming, vectorization, tidyverse, na

I have code and it works correctly:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df<-data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "Time"=c("1999-12-31 10:10:10","1999-12-31 09:05:13","1999-12-31 00:05:25","1999-12-31 00:07:04","1999-12-31 03:05:07"))
tib<-as_tibble(df)

time_converted_data_1<-tib
time_converted_data_2<-tib

time_converted_data_1$Time<-unlist(lapply(tib$Time, function(x) period_to_seconds(hms(paste(hour(x), minute(x), second(x), sep = ":")))))

time_converted_data_2$Time<-period_to_seconds(hms(paste(hour(tib$Time), minute(tib$Time), second(tib$Time), sep = ":")))
```

But if I change:

```
df<-data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "Time"=c("1999-12-31 10:10:10","1999-12-31 09:05:13","1999-12-31 00:05:25","1999-12-31 00:07:04","1999-12-31 03:05:07"))
```

to (changing last value to `NA`):

```
df<-data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5), "Time"=c("1999-12-31 10:10:10","1999-12-31 09:05:13","1999-12-31 00:05:25","1999-12-31 00:07:04", NA))
```

than I receive warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
  Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
2: In .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
  Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
```

I tried to use `is.na()` in different ways but without any luck.

**Question:** Does this warning affects calculations? Is it safe to use as it is now?

Comment: subset NA first, then do time conversion and finally cbind NA's.

Comment: That's a warning, not an error.

Comment: @Not_Dave It gives me result. But is it safe to use it with this warning? *Also edited my question to reflect that.*

Comment: @r2evans you are right. I am just quite new to R. Thank you form mentioning it. Corrected my question.

Comment: Usually u want to remove NA as it might affect the repeatability of your results.

Comment: @Not_Dave data has many other variables and sample size is too low. So at that moment we decided to keep every observation.

Comment: @vasili111 in that case see if you can impute those missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is only alarming if you thought that all values were legitimate: with that assumption, the warning could identify that somewhere, in the middle of your data, is something *corrupted*. With larger datasets (perhaps live or un-curated), this could be an indicator of something else with the data.

In general, warnings are there because the author believes that there is a condition you may not be aware of that might affect the correctness/completeness of the overall processing/analysis.

In this case, however, I suspect that it is *not surprising to you*, in which case there is one technique you can use to avoid that specific warning. Other techniques exist that **suppress** *all warnings*, but that's a bit nuclear and will mask other issues you haven't yet found. In general, I'm a fan of avoiding known problems so that you do not become "numb" to warnings and start ignoring them.

```r
### "normal" way
tib$Time1 <- period_to_seconds(hms(paste(hour(tib$Time), minute(tib$Time), second(tib$Time), sep = ":")))
# Warning in .parse_hms(..., order = "HMS", quiet = quiet) :
#   Some strings failed to parse, or all strings are NAs
tib$Time1
# [1] 36610 32713   325   424    NA

### *avoid* the warning, no suppression, just not trying to parse "known-NA"
tib$Time2 <- NA
notna <- !is.na(tib$Time)
tib$Time2[notna] <- period_to_seconds(hms(paste(hour(tib$Time[notna]),
  minute(tib$Time[notna]), second(tib$Time[notna]), sep = ":")))
tib$Time2
# [1] 36610 32713   325   424    NA
```

Comment: I think you accidentally omitted some code: `Error in NextMethod("[") : object 'notna' not found`.

Comment: Yup, partial copying/pasting from a debug pane ... thanks.

Comment: Thank you for a such beautiful solution!  1. As I understand `notna <- !is.na(tib$Time)` means that "give actual `tib$Time` value if current cell value is not `NA`", but what it gives when `tib$Time==NA`? Empty string? `NA` value? Other? I am trying to understand how exactly it works. 2. What is `notna` in this case? Function or variable? `typeof` and `mode` giving me "logical", so it is just variable of type "logical"?

Comment: (1) don't use `==NA`, b/c any (in)equality comparison with `NA` yields a logical `NA`, not a T/F. (2) `notna` indicates which value is *not `NA`*, meaning something you want to try to parse. When you convert all non-`NA` values to a `POSIXt` class value, all `NA` values remain `NA`s. Using `tib$Time[notna] <- ...` only replaces the positions with actual values. (3) You ask *"what is `notna`"* ... have you tried the code? It's just a `logical` vector indicating which positions in `tib$Time` are not `NA`.